# Release space deleted 'with no datacopy' in sybase database

Tags: sybase

If  I drop a column from a table in my sybase database, I use the command

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP columnName WITH NO DATACOPY
```

What is the command to actively release the space on the disk of the columns ?

In oracle, the aquivalent command would be

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP UNUSED COLUMNS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself, the command would be:

```
REORG REBUILD tableName
```